# Understanding docker plugins

Tags: plugins, docker

I see some guys talking about the docker plugins. But, I couldn't find anything on the docker docs about it. Can someone help me with this. Is there anything like docker plugin. I basically want to extend docker either via a plugin or else I have to fork it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess these guy want say plugins to others software can have Docker integration. How Jenkins has.

- https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Docker+Plugin

Do you saw Docker plugin to Jenkins?